# Android compose Modifier width unexpected behaviour inside scrollable/lazy row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, modifier, composable

I am building a basic layout which diplays a horizontally scrollable row with cards. The cards are a column component with a couple dividers in the middle:

```
@Composable
fun TestCard(
  name: String
) {
  Column(
    modifier = Modifier
      .background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
      .padding(12.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
  ) {
    Text(text = name, style = Typography.h4.bold.black)
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
    Divider(color = Color.Black) //DOES NOT APPEAR IN ROW
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
    Divider(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), color = Color.Black) //DOES NOT APPEAR IN ROW
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
    Text(text = "Other text", style = Typography.h4.bold.black)
  }
}
```

I also have a scrollable row that contains a list of these cards:

```
@Composable
fun TestComponent() {

  val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
  val names = listOf("Martha", "Erik","Steve","Roy","Pete")

  Column(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
  ) {
    Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll(scrollState), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
      names.forEach { name ->
        TestCard(name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I display the card on its own, I can see both dividers. When I display the row containing cards the dividers don't appear, because their width is set to 0 (I can verify with LayoutInspector the dividers are there). Visual representation:

[image: example]

I know I can create a state variable for width that would be updated inside the `Modifier.onSizeChanged` but I am sure there must be a reason for this to happen and a better solution.

Comment: You have to specify the width (also for the `Spacer`).
The `Divider` has inside a `fillMaxWidth()` modifier, but as you check in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxWidth(kotlin.Float)): `If the incoming maximum width is Constraints.Infinity this modifier will have no effect` and it happens because of the `horizontalScroll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Divider` has inside a `fillMaxWidth()` modifier, but as you check in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxWidth(kotlin.Float)):

> If the incoming maximum width is `Constraints.Infinity` this modifier will have no effect.

It happens because of the `horizontalScroll`.
You have to specify the width for the `Divider`s and the `Spacer`s.

A workaround is to apply `width(IntrinsicSize.Max)` to the `Column` in the `TestCard`. In this way the Constraints have a `Constraints.fixedWidth(width)`:

```
@Composable
fun TestCard(
    name: String
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            .background(androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
            .padding(12.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
    ) {
        Text(text = name,)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp).fillMaxWidth())
        Divider(color = Color.Black, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) 
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp).fillMaxWidth())
        Divider(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), color = Color.Black) 
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp).fillMaxWidth())
        Text(text = "Other text" )
    }

}
```

Comment: This works great, I have also realised that if the container's width is specified such as with ```IntrinsicSize.Max```, there is no need to add the ```.fillMaxWidth``` modifier to the Dividers.